# Same Files different sizes

Tags: css

i have a strange problem, i had a domain on a subdomain to fill the texts and for testing to find bugs and so.. yesterday we finished the pre-work and the we were ready to move the whole files to the real domain (LIVE) so i downloaded the files from the subdomain and uploaded them to the real domain.

but here are some things that are really strange, when i open two tabs (FIREFOX!!!) one tab with the subdomain and one tab with the real domain and i switch about the tabs you can see its jumping and the sizes are not equal.

Subdomain: http://lechner.ep-vorschau.at
Domain: http://bestattunglechner.at

Comment: Looking absolutely identical to me.

Comment: Exactly the same in Firefox 40.0.3.

Comment: i have 41.0 - do you know anything that could cause this problem?

Comment: Is there any chance you've maybe zoomed in on the Preview Page? (http://lechner.ep-vorschau.at) Seems obvious but happened to me once.

Comment: If you _really_ do not have zoomed your view accidentally, then check with the development console inside the browser for the computed dimensions of the container elements.

Comment: Press `CTRL + 0` in both tabs.

Comment: oh my good... yes i really zoomed into the preview-page it was on 110% thanks guys if spent many hours to find the "Bug" and who is the bug? the user ... haha like most of the time!! thanks guys!

Comment: You're welcome! The most obvious bugs are always the hardest to find. :)